# Raspberry Pi 4 - IP can be obtained via DHCP but is not assigned to dev eth0

Tags: networking, raspbian

After a reboot I ran into a strange problem. I can see that the raspberry obtains an IP address (DHCPACK) but for some reason it is not assigned to eth0. If I try to assign an IP address manually (ip addr add IP/Netmask dev eth0) I can ping the host for one or two seconds until eth0 loses the IP address assignment again. (ip a shows NO-CARRIER and DOWN)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a defective Switch Port.